# Python PyVISA USB connection issue

Tags: python, connection, usb, visa

I am trying to program a semi-automatic probing station in my lab. Specifically, the P200L from Micromanipulator, which is controlled by a ESP301 Motion Controller.

I have been trying to use PyVISA to communicate with the device but am running into problems simply establishing a basic connection.

```
In [1]: import visa
In [2]: rm = visa.ResourceManager()
In [3]: rm.list_resources()
Out [3]:(u'ASRL1::INSTR', u'ASRL3::INSTR', u'ASRL4::INSTR')
```

However, the P200L is using a USB to USB connection that I am not seeing on the actual list of resources. However, when I disconnect the USB `u'ASRL4::INSTR'`disappears so I assuming that's what the connection is being read as?.

I am relatively new to Python, any help/advice would be great.

Comment: Have you tried sending any commands to the `ASRL4::INSTR` instrument to see if it responds? I don't think the ESP301 responds to a *IDN command, but you could look through the manual and find another simple command and try that. Keep an eye on whether it switches to remote mode when doing that...